# CPU Usage high for my CSS Animation. Can I use the GPU to lessen the burden?

Tags: css, gpu, css-animations, cpu-usage, css-transforms

I made the following Animation to play while the page is loading.

HTML
           `<div class="skeleton"></div>`

CSS

```
      @keyframes shimmerBackground {
        0% { background-position: -468px 0 }
        100% { background-position: 468px 0 }
      }

      .skeleton:empty{
          width: 500px;
          height: 40px;
          animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
         animation-iteration-count: infinite;
         background: no-repeat #e4e3e3;
         background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #e4e3e3 0, #c7c6c6 20%, #e4e3e3 40%, #e4e3e3 100%);
         animation: shimmerBackground 1s linear infinite;
      }
```

Here it is in action: https://jsfiddle.net/NuccioJohn/fx1wr8e6/

The animation correctly stops itself after the element is loaded with the data. But the hit to the CPU from Painting and Rendering is absolutely absurd.

I have been able to use other methods to lower the CPU usage significantly, but these methods do not work in IE 11 and having it work in IE is a must.

My instinct is that I should be able to use the GPU to do this animation, and that will lessen the burden this animation has on the GPU.

`transform: translateZ(0);`

Does anyone know how to rewrite this in a more efficient manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work? Instead of directly animating the background image, which requires a repaint for each frame, try using `transform: translate3d()` on a pseudo element. The included z-axis in `translate3d()` will force GPU rendering too!

```
@keyframes shimmerBackground {
  0% { transform: translate3d(-400px, 0, 0) }
  100% { transform: translate3d(900px, 0, 0) }
}

.skeleton:empty{
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e4e3e3;
}

.skeleton:empty::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: no-repeat #e4e3e3;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #e4e3e3 0, #c7c6c6 20%, #e4e3e3 40%, #e4e3e3 100%);
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation: shimmerBackground 1s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: This answer resolves the issue. The rendering and paint impact is significantly reduced. Thank you so much. One issue that remains is that I only showed a very reduced version of the code, so that I would hide specific details about my client. The animation is actually the background of a table. I have transparent TD's with thickened borders in the table and you can see the animation through the transparent TD's. When I try to implement this animation into the table, it moves the entire tables background. If I can't figure it out, can I ask you for more advice on this issue in the future?

Comment: @nuccio No promises I'll be able to help, but it doesn't hurt to take a look!